# How to lookup character from Word using getScore?

Tags: java

Created a class Word. The purpose of this class is to take in words from players using a linked list.  The Player class uses the word to get a score value for each character.  I'm confused how to get each character using the object Word using a method getScore in the class Player.

```
public class Word{
 private String guessWord;

 public Word(String w){
  if(w.length() < 1)
   throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid entry.");

  guessWord = w.toUpperCase(); 
 }

 public String getWord(){
  String input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter your word: ");
  guessWord = input;
  return guessWord;
 }


}

public class Player {
 private String name;
 WordList list = new WordList();

 public Player(String name){
  if(name == null || name.equals(" "))
   throw new IllegalArgumentException("Must enter a name!!!");
  this.name = name;

 }

 public void addWord(Word w){
   list.append(w);
 }
 public int getScore(){
  if(Character.isLetter(letters))
  if( == 'A' || letters == 'E' || letters == 'I' || letters == 'O' || letters == 'U') 
   return 0;
  else if(letters == 'K' || letters == 'V' || letters == 'F' || letters == 'W') return 5;
  else if(letters == 'X' || letters == 'Q') return 10;
  } // If statement
 }
 public String getName(){
  return name;
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get a character of a `String` returned by `getWord` using the [charAt](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#charAt%28int%29) method, for example:

```
String s = word.getWord();
for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
    char c = s.charAt(i);
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Do I create a Word variable within the method getScore?

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to convert the `guessWord` of Word object which is returned fron `getWord()` to a character array and loop through it. am i correct? if so

```
String letters = word.getWord();
   for(int i = 0; i < letters.length; i++){
       if(Character.isLetter(letters.charAt(i)))
       //your code
   }
```

i think this may help you cheers !

Comment: sorry, i just saw the previous answer.